# Can't save time component of DATETIME  to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can't save the time component of my `DATETIME` to SQL Server.

Current result in SQL Server is `2012-08-24 00:00:00:000` but I want the current time in SQL Server `2012-08-24 14:25:50:789`

```
private void Invoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTimeCurrent.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();  
}

private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbl_AsInvoice inv = new tbl_AsInvoice();
    inv.AsInvMDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimeCurrent.Text).Date;
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        db.tbl_AsInvoices.InsertOnSubmit(inv);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        ts.Complete();
    }
}
```

---

I try

```
inv.AsInvMDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimeCurrent.Text);
```

It don't working. T_T

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server **has no format** - it's an 8-byte numerical value. The format only comes into play when you want to display that datetime. When you read the `DATETIME` value from SQL Server in your C# code - leave it up to the C# code to handle the displaying of the date in the proper format! SQL Server just **stores** the date time - without any formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Change your statement:

```
inv.AsInvMDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimeCurrent.Text).Date;
```

To:

```
inv.AsInvMDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimeCurrent.Text);
```

You are currently saving the `Date` part only, you need to save the complete `DateTime`